# Issue Inserting Row MySQL, no MySQL Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php script snippet:

```
try{
  $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$databaseName;charset=utf8",$user,$pass);
  $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
  $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $dat = $_REQUEST['dat'];
  $poll = $dat[0];
  $date = $dat[1];
  $zip = $dat[2];
  $answer = $dat[3];

  $q = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO votes (poll_id, date, location, answers) VALUES (:poll, :date, :zip, :answer)");
  $q->bindParam(':poll', $poll, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $q->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $q->bindParam(':zip', $zip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $q->bindParam(':answer', $answer, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  if ($q->execute){
     echo "worked";
  } else {
     echo "didn't work";
  }
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Every time I try and run this script, I get an internal server error (500).  There is no echo, no error message, nothing.  When I remove the error handling, I get 200, but the "didn't work" message.

Please help!

EDIT:  Added ini_set("display_errors",1); to top of page.  Some reason 500 error no longer occurs, but still getting "didn't work".

Comment: Turn on your php errors. Add `ini_set("display_errors",1);` at the top of your file.

Comment: Added, somehow the 500 error is now gone, but still receiving "didn't work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to change `if ($q->execute){` to `if ($q->execute()){`

Comment: Buy @Alon a beer! Thanks! Will accept answer in couple minutes (once I get permission to =] )